# How to use DataFormatter in EventBasedExcelExtractor

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to use DataFormatter with EventBasedExcelExtractor. The problem is that text from numrec.getValue() is not formatted as they are in the excel files. Even using FormatTrackingHSSFListener does not guarantee the extracted value to be exactly like the value represented in the excel file.

Comment: Why isn't `FormatTrackingHSSFListener` good enough? It seems to work well enough for lots of things, such as [EventBasedExcelExtractor](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/EventBasedExcelExtractor.java) from POI itself!

Comment: Because it doesn't always return the correct format. For example 6/6/2007 will be 6/6/07, etc. I am comparing many excel files to see if a set of many pdfs are the exact conversions of the excel files. I need the text to be exact to determine if the pdf is an exact conversion or a conversion of a slightly different file.

Comment: Are you sure that your excel file actually has the formats in it that you think it does? Excel is known to lie about formats, and silently substitute in different ones in certain locales...

Comment: The dates are formatted as 6/9/2007 in the excel file and are returned correctly using PDFBox but when I get text without using FormatTrackingHSSFListener, it returns 39242.00. With the FormatTrackingHSSFListener, it returns 6/9/07. Furthermore, all integers are returned with a decimal so 2 will be returned as 2.0.

Comment: Almost all numbers are stored in excel as floating points, including dates, so that's all as expected. If you want it to be simple, buy some more memory and use UserModel!

Comment: Okay, now I'm using the UserModel and HSSFDataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell). The integers are returning correctly but the dates are still returning as 6/9/07 no matter what date format they are in. I guess Adobe pdfs are converted pixel by pixel and I will never be able to use POI excel text extraction to compare these files exactly. Is this correct?

Comment: Assuming you're using the latest version of Apache POI, then what you're seeing is something that is an annoying feature of excel, where it sometimes writes a different format string to the file than the one it actually uses itself...